# How do I remove a cell from a column

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Hi I have this listview,

```
ID Name
0  Josh
1  John
2  Joseph
3  Jack
4  Jacky
```

I would like to remove Josh and get the following outcome:

```
ID Name
0  John
1  Joseph
2  Jack
3  Jacky
4
```

How can I go in doing that? My XAML bindings:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Comment: post the data binding part

Comment: I've only used those bindings to add items to my listview via ListView1.Items.Add(new {ID = 0, Name="Josh"}); etc..

Comment: Thats something u shud do from your viewmodel/code behind,.. Its not removing a cell from view .. Your view should match data bound object.. Change the bound object see the list view updating

Comment: I'm adding the items via code. I am just wonder how I would remove them via code using C#

Comment: post the adding items part